# QComboBox items and their values are the function of other textbox, how to use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a GUI consist of three text box and the numeric value of three text box is stored in variable a, b, c, respectively. That GUI also contains a Combobox, and it's (combobox) items are defined by:

```
item_array=numpy.arange(a,b,c)
```

How I can update the Combobox items dynamically after entering the variables in three textboxes?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your text box (Qlineedit) to a function that sets the text in the Qcombobox when the Qlineedit has been edited:

```
    Qlineedit.textchanged.connect(set_func)

    def set_func():
        text = Qlinedit.text()
        Qcombobox.setCurrentText(text)
```

Comment: No problem Nikita Sharma. If it was helpful would you mind up voting or even marking it as the answer :)